# How to get softtabstop to go back in spaces with backspace?

Tags: formatting, softtabstop

I watched a video tutorial about optimising tabs vs spaces. I made no changes but I noticed something in the video that isn't happening for me.

When he pressed `backspace`, he went back one space at a time. His settings are the same as mine:

```
set sw=4 tw=4 sts=0 expandtab
```

But when I press backspace in insert mode I jump back by 4 spaces, instead of 1 space at a time. I experimented with `vim -u NONE` and the effect is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Note - I am using neovim. In the video I watched he was using vim. Not sure that matters.

Comment: Neovim automatically sets smarttab. `set nosmarttab` solved it!